# Alternative to Translate Animation

Tags: android, button, scroll, translate-animation

I finally came to know that when using translate animation, the button onclick listener won't work.

[This is the link to the full description of my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428281/marquee-of-thumbnail-images)

Now I would like to know what is the alternative options to try instead of Translate Animation.

Comment: This brief question is entirely reliant on a deleted question, so this question should also be closed and deleted. Voting as "unclear" for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your own animation using a thread.

I can give you an example.

1. Put your view to animate inside a Relative Layout.
2. Then start a thread which is running a loop with specific delay time and then set the margin of the view that you need to animate with different values..

This will give you the effect of translate animation and the view will be intractable also.